# how get values of part of json object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json object:

```
{"images":{"2":"building.jpg","3":"campus.jpg","4":"grads.jpg","5":"trio.jpg"},"videos":[]}
```

I'm using this code to get the number of images:

```
var imgCount = Object.keys(obj.images).length;
```

But how do I get the values of those images (building.jpg, etc.)? I confess I'm having a hard time with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if this is the solution you are looking for, but you can access them, in this case, like

```
obj.images["2"] //"building.jpg"
obj.images["3"] //"campus.jpg"
obj.images["4"] //"grads.jpg"
obj.images["5"] //"trio.jpg"
```

Keep in mind that there is nothing unusual happening here.
You are accessing an object through it's property's name. In this case, the object is obj.images, and the property names are 2, 3, 4 and 5.